# How do I get rid of the excess space on the mobile version of a wufoo form?

Tags: css, wufoo

On google chrome, the mobile version of the wufoo form is showing up exactly how I want it to (see picture below):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cdJY.png)

But on my iPhone, there is an excess space that I can't seem to get rid of at the top of the form (see picture below):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i12NN.png)

When I messaged WuFoo about this problem, they said they do not provide help for custom css issues. Since my google chrome developer tools doesn't show the issue, I'm stuck. Does anyone know how I can get rid of this excess space?

Thanks!

Comment: When asking a question on StackOverflow, you should include all relevant code, so that we can reproduce the problem and help you with it. More info at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I apologize. Here is a link to the form: https://esserslosangeles.wufoo.com/forms/p12tlynk0fwpiji/

Comment: My issue is that google chrome is not accurately displaying the mobile version of the form. So I cannot find out why there is extra space at the top on mobile.

Comment: Here is my custom css code:

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to remove the `padding-top: 20vh` from your `html` -element when the page is displayed on a narrow device.

In that case, this CSS should do what you want. I've reused the same `@media` -query that is used on your page already, with the assumption that that is the size you define to be for *mobile devices*.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    html {padding-top: 0}
}
```

If you add this code snippet to the end of your CSS file (probably `wufoo.css`), it should remove the space above the form on mobile devices.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and helping me explore this issue! Unfortunately, this code snippet didn't work. I'm having the issue that absolutely any @ media query I put for mobile isn't working. Do you know why? I even tried @ media only screen and (max-width:700px) { html{padding-top:0;} } Do you think there might be an issue in the html of the page? I do not have access to edit the html, so I don't know what to do. Thank you again for your help and advice!! It is much appreciated :)